# WaitForTitle does not work

Tags: selenium-ide

I have the following pattern sprinkled through my Selenium IDE test suite:

```
WaitForTitle    Login

Pause           2000

SelectWindow    Login
```

The WaitForTitle always fails, but the test continues. The SelectWindow always passes. However, if I remove the WaitForTitle, the Select Window starts failing much of the time.

My question is why would SelectWindow Login pass but WaitForTitle Login fail?

Comment: What is the title of page? Does it contain Login? Take a look: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/11/tutorial-post-for-selenium-ide.html as well.

Comment: The pattern you described is confusing. Why would you `pause 2000ms` (I presume) if the page has already loaded with `WaitForTitle`? Can you provide a `code` example? There is really not much anyone can help with due to a vague question.

Comment: I removed the Pause, but the problem still persists. Now the "WaitForTitle Login" always fails, but "SelectWindow Login" always passes. My question is why does WaitForTitle always fail?

Comment: From the steps described I'm assuming that the 'Login' page is a new window opening up that you need to switch to. WaitForTitle only interacts with the currently selected window, so it wouldn't interact with the window you're trying to select before you do so. As for why the SelectWindow fails when you remove the WaitForTitle, I'm guessing it will just be loading time. Selenium IDE has a timeout for 'WaitFor' commands (usually 30 seconds but you may have changed this). Without the WaitForTitle the script will try to select the window immediatley, when the page title may not have loaded.